# Calculating shape of conv1d layer in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, size

How we can calculate the shape of conv1d layer in PyTorch. IS there any command to calculate size and shape of these layers in PyTorch.

````
            nn.Conv1d(depth_1, depth_2, kernel_size=kernel_size_2, stride=stride_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=stride_size),
            nn.Dropout(0.25)```
````

Answer (score 1):

The output size can be calculated as shown in the documentation [`nn.Conv1d` - Shape](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv1d):

> [image: Conv1d size]

The batch size remains unchanged and you already know the number of channels, since you specified them when creating the convolution (`depth_2` in this example).

Only the length needs to be calculated and you can do that with a simple function analogous to the formula above:

```py
def calculate_output_length(length_in, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1):
    return (length_in + 2 * padding - dilation * (kernel_size - 1) - 1) // stride + 1
```

The default values specified are also the default values of `nn.Conv1d`, therefore you only need to specify what you also specify to create the convolution. It uses an integer division `//`, because the numerator might be not be divisible by `stride`, in which case it just gets rounded down (indicated by the brackets that are only closed at towards the bottom).

The same formula also applies to [`nn.MaxPool1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.MaxPool1d), but keep in mind that it automatically sets `stride = kernel_size` if `stride` is not specified.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Lin in this formula should be depth_1 in my case?. Am I right?. Because in conv1d(input,output,kernel_size,stride)

Comment: No, these are the channels, not the length, so `depth_1` is `C_in` and `depth_2` is `C_out`. The convolution is independent of the length, which makes it possible to use inputs with different lengths. It depends on the input you are feeding to the model, which would have size *[batch_size, in_channels, length]*.